# Capture bash output and compare it to a line of text

Tags: bash, output, comparison, nagios

I've just joined Stackoverflow because I need some help. I've been doing some basic management of our Red Hat server because we run Nagios on it, but I've been asked to make some scripts for monitoring our SAP environment.

I've modified the SAP servers and a CCMS plugin to retourn the output we need:

EU_PUT History = EU_PUT | 00101401 | Afgebroken |, started at 2016-10-20,00:10:18 terminated at 2016-10-20,00:10:18

I want to use the captured output (^) and check if it contains the word 'Beënd'. If it does it means the job ended succesfully, if it does not it means the job failed (regardless of failed status). Whatever I do, the script does not pick up on the output. The output is succesfully shown when running the below script but the comparison is not working.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,
Dennis Lans

```
   #!/bin/bash
    T1="*Beënd*"

    #For Nagios reporting purposes:
    unknown="0"
    ok="1"
    warning="2"
    critical="3"

    output=$(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_sap job_eu_put lnx '2>&1')

    if [[ "$output" == "$T1" ]]
        then
            echo $output
            exit $ok
        else
            echo $output
            exit $critical

    fi
```

Comment: Why are you enclosing the redirection in quotes? And have you taken a look at what *output* really contains when it fails a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosing redirections in quotes is not a good practice. More importantly though, your if statement `[[ "$output" == "$T1" ]]` does a strict comparison, it does not ask if `$T1` is a substring of `$output`. You should use `[[ "$output" == *"$T1"* ]]` for that. That is, the `*` should not be placed inside quotes, as you have in your definition of your `T1` variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
T1="Beënd"

#For Nagios reporting purposes:
unknown="0"
ok="1"
warning="2"
critical="3"

output=$(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_sap job_eu_put lnx '2>&1')

if [[ "$output" == *"$T1"* ]]
    then
        echo $output
        exit $ok
    else
        echo $output
        exit $critical

fi
```

Comment: Thanks! This works just perfectly. I'll save the url and your tips in our documentation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you aren't redirecting standard error properly. When you enclose the redirection in quotes, as you have with `'2>&1'`, you are actually just passing a string as an argument. For example:

```
$ echo foo '>/dev/null'
foo >/dev/null
```

Once you fix your redirection, you might also want to ensure that your *output* variable contains the values that you think it should. A common source of error is doing string comparisons when one of the strings contains newlines or leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I've changed that in my script. That together with the comment from jmd_dk made the script work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the stderr to stdout redirection quotes from 2>&1

```
  output=$(blah 2>&1)
  echo $output
  No command 'blah' found, did you mean: Command 'blam' from package 'blam' (universe) blah: command not found
```